# How to read data from beginning only once per group in kafka topic?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, consumer, confluent-kafka-python

I'm using `confluent-kafka` KafkaConsumer library for reading data from kafka. Here is the scenario.

1. `Demo` topic is compaction enabled.
2. Consumer-1 is reading data using the latest property with a group.id="group-1".
3. Now I want Consumer-2 to read all data from the beginning in topic with group.id="group-2".
4. When I use `auto.offset.reset="earliest"` it reads data from the beginning, but in case the consumer restarts then it again reads data from the beginning.

How should I configure new consumer-2 so that it will read data from the **beginning only once**, after this, it will give only the not acknowledged data.

Thanks

Comment: When a consumer starts and is assigned a partition to consume, it will start at its group’s committed offset or latest or ealiest as auto.offset.reset (When there is a committed offset, the auto.offset.reset property is not used).   [Confluent Configuration](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#consumerconfigs_auto.offset.reset)

Comment: is it possible to read data from-beginning with offset commit so that this read data will not come when consumer restarts?

Comment: I think i would first check is at what frequency are you commiting offset(if not using the default autocommit flag) and describe a consumer group to check the lag and stuff.


Then i would look deep into two more configuration.
`
    "enable.auto.commit" : "true",// default is true as well
    "auto.commit.interval.ms" : "1000" 
`